# Capturing x and y coordinates of page in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coordinates

I am using a jquery plugin to display page. I am able to capture coordinates of entire page in Chrome and IE but when i try to do the same with Firefox, it captures the screen coordinates and not the page. Can somebody help.

Code :

```
$('.page').bind('click', function(event) {      

    var x;
    var y;


    if (!(event.offsetX || event.offsetY)) {

     x = event.clientX;
         y = event.clientY;

        }
        else {
            x = event.offsetX;
            y = event.offsetY;
        }               

    alert("x :" +x +", y: " +y);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're using jQuery, use the `pageX` and `pageY` attributes of the event object that [jQuery normalizes for you](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). From that link:

> **Event Properties**
>
> jQuery normalizes the following properties for cross-browser consistency:
>
> - target
> - relatedTarget
> - **pageX**
> - **pageY**
> - which
> - metaKey

*(My emphasis.)*

Those will reliably be relative to the document. If you're trying to get coordinates relative to the element in which the event occurred, you can find that element's position via [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset) and then do the math:

```
$(".page").click(function(event) {
    var pos = $(this).offset();

    console.log("Click relative to document: " + event.pageX + "x" + event.pageY);
    pos.left = event.pageX - pos.left;
    pos.top  = event.pageY - pos.top;
    console.log("Click relative to element:  " + pos.left + "x" + pos.top);
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ejabet/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ejabet/1/edit)

Comment: I did using that too. I get the coordinates in firefox but they are of the screen and not the page. So when i scroll down the coordinates remains the same. :/

Comment: Ooh, [relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.relatedTarget). Your answers always seem to lead to new, and interesting, things... =)

Comment: @shabbir.rang: No, they're not the coordinates on the screen. They're the coordinates on the document. Are you trying to find out what the coordinates are relative to the *element*?

Comment: @DavidThomas: If so, it's because you make the effort to make it so. :-) (And thanks!)

Comment: I tried it out on ff.. just need to check it on my project. Thanks a ton!!